# Method parameter problem in self programmed Binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

I programmed a Binary-Tree, now I am facing a problem during printing in order. When I call my `printIO` method, the `printIO`method calls another method which requires as parameter the root Node (as I print recursively) the method calls each time and passes the next node.

**Is there any way to print the tree without 2 methods and no parameter in the main?**

**Idea:**
make the temp Node static and don't use a parameter in the final print method. This didn't worked, as I got some Exceptions. Any idea?

**Code snippet main**:

```
 BinList bl = new BinList();
 bl.add(9);
 bl.add(7);
 ...
 bl.printIO();
```

**Code snippet of the List Class:**

```
public void printIO() {
    print_in_order(root);
}

private void print_in_order(Node temp) {
    if (temp != null) {
        print_in_order(temp.left);
        System.out.println(temp.data);
        print_in_order(temp.right);
    }
}
```

Comment: please post a [mcve].  Thanks

Comment: What you have is perfectly fine (except for the disrespect of naming conventions). Why do you want to change it?

Comment: It might help to also mention what the exceptions are

Comment: @JBNizet In guess it's better tho when there is a solution with only one called method(Performance etc.(also if it's very little))

Comment: @Quintium Null-Pointer E.

Comment: @Alan if the goal is to improve performance, avoiding a single method call won't change anything. And introducing a static variable, making the algorithm stateful, is a terrible design idea. Premature optimization is the root of all evil: you're going to make the design much worse, more complex, to try to solve a performance problem which doesn't exist, and actually not change anything to the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of printing in the `BinList` class you should split the responsability between the `BinList` class and the `Node`  class:

```
public class BinList {
    private Node root = ...;

    public void printInOrder() {
        if (root != null) {
            root.printInOrder();
        }
    }
}

public class Node {
    private Node left, right;
    private Object data;

    public void printInOrder() {
        if (left != null) {
            left.printInOrder();
        }
        System.out.printl(data);
        if (right != null) {
            right.printInOrder();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Worked!